# Copying a list(ObservableCollection) to another

Tags: c#, list, system.reactive

I have a list which is has many updates at real time so I want to copy all the changes in  this Observable Collection to another after every 1 sec.How can I do that?

What I tried is:

```
var temp = CalculateMyObservableCollection();
var temp2 = (INotifyCollectionChanged) temp.SourceCollection;

Observable.FromEventPattern<CollectionChangeEventArgs>(temp2, "CollectionChanged")
                .Throttle(new TimeSpan(1000))
                .Select(i => i.Sender)
                .Subscribe(UpdateItems);

private void UpdateItems(object obj)
{
    if (obj is MyClass)
        Items.AddNewItem(obj as MyClass);
}
```

Which seems quite wrong!!

Comment: Show which you say `I have a list` and `which is has many updates at real time` and `this Observable Collection`. Then we will show `How can I do that`.

Comment: `yourCollection.ToList()` ?

Comment: Try signing CollectionChanged event

Comment: Can you explain more about why you want to do this? I am wondering if a thread-safe collection is more appropriate -  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Since I want to bind this collection to UI and if I bind it directly UI gets freeze in case of too many updates.So I was thinking to update my datasource after every 1 second.

Comment: @Gandarez : and how to proceed further to add these changes in temp2 after every second?

Comment: @vkg Why do you need it to be copied every 1 sec and not at real time?

Comment: because gui gets freeze due to too many updates!! So was thinking to throttle the binding in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a throttled observable collection that perhaps can solve your problem.

The `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface can provide detailed change notifications describing the exact collection changes where the change action is indicated by the [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs.action(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the event args. However, when changes are being throttled you loose the ability to track details about the change because complex changes where elements are both added and removed cannot be expressed. Instead the [Reset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedaction(v=vs.110).aspx) action has to be used to signal that *the content of the collection changed dramatically*.

```
class ThrottledObservableCollection<T> : IReadOnlyCollection<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable {

  List<T> _list;

  IDisposable _subscription;

  public ThrottledObservableCollection(ObservableCollection<T> source, TimeSpan throttleInterval) {
    if (source == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    _list = new List<T>(source);
    _subscription = Observable
      .FromEventPattern<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(
        handler => source.CollectionChanged += handler,
        handler => source.CollectionChanged -= handler
      )
      .Throttle(throttleInterval)
      .Subscribe(HandleSourceChanged);
  }

  void HandleSourceChanged(EventPattern<NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs> eventPattern) {
    var source = (IEnumerable<T>) eventPattern.Sender;
    _list = new List<T>(source);
    OnPropertyChanged("Count");
    OnCollectionChanged();
  }

  public Int32 Count { get { return _list.Count; } }

  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
    return _list.GetEnumerator();
  }

  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
    return GetEnumerator();
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName) {
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
      handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

  protected void OnCollectionChanged() {
    var handler = CollectionChanged;
    if (handler != null)
      handler(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
  }

  public void Dispose() {
    Dispose(true);
  }

  protected void Dispose(Boolean disposing) {
    _subscription.Dispose();
  }

}
```

Note that this class is not thread-safe and you probably need some additional protection if the source collection is changed simultaneously by multiple threads.

Here is how to use the collection:

```
var observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
var throttledObservableCollection = new ThrottledObservableCollection<Item>(
  observableCollection,
  TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
);
throttledObservableCollection.CollectionChanged += ...

// 2 CollectionChanged events will fire from this code.
observableCollection.Add(new Item());
observableCollection.Add(new Item());
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.1));
observableCollection.Add(new Item());
```

Comment: converting Source->Items(Observable collection to list) is a good idea? Will it notify changes in source?

Comment: @vkg: My code uses Rx which assumes that no overlapping events are fired from the source collection. This assumption is false if the source collection is changed simultaneously by multiple threads and in that case the `_list` field may be mutated by multiple threads in an unexpected manner. Your second question about _"Will it notify changes in source?"_ Yes, that is the point of this solution that you get throttled notifications about changes to the source.

Comment: AHH..That was silly question as we are just referring to source in _list = new List<T>(source) !!

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments say it would be better to give more detailed why you need to do this.

It does appears all you want is the identity ('sender') of the object which changed the observable collection, in which case what about duplicates in the list?

But if you can't why aren't you using the Buffer operator:

```
   Observable.FromEventPattern<CollectionChangeEventArgs>(temp2, "CollectionChanged")
             .Buffer(new TimeSpan(1000))
             .Where(x => x.Any())
             .Select(x => i.Sender)
             .Subscribe(UpdateItems);
```